# javascript don't work after change content by ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

when I change page content by ajax , my functions stop working . this is my scripts :

```
$function(){
    $( 'input[name="formtype"]:radio' ).change(
        function(){
            var formtype = $('input[name=formtype]:checked').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/changeform.php',
                method: 'post',
                data: {"type": formtype},
                success: function (data) {
                    $(form).html(data);
                }
            })
       }
    );

    $('input[name="set_address"]').on('change', function () {
        $('input[name="university"]').prop('disabled',false);
        $('input[name="school"]').prop('disabled',false);
    }
}
```

this is my base content :

```
<body>
    <input type="radio" name="formtype" value="1" checked>
    <input type="radio" name="formtype" value="2">

    <form method="post" action="action.php">
       <input type="checkbox" name="set_address" checked>
       <input type="text" name="university" disabled>
    </form>
</body>
```

when "formtype" change , ajax returns this form's content:

```
       <input type="checkbox" name="set_address" checked>
       <input type="text" name="school" disabled>
```

now when I uncheck "set_address" checkbox the school input don't active.
how can I solve it?

Comment: You can use $(document).on('change','yourselector',function(){ //your code here})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently what you are using is called a "direct" binding which will only attach to element that exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

You need to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach, when generating elements dynamically or manipulation selector (like removing and adding classes) or **replacing elements**.

*i.e.*

```
$(parentStaticContainer).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

*Example*

```
$('form').on('change', 'input[name="set_address"]', function(){
    //Your code
});
```

Comment: It's a `change` event, not `click`.

Comment: It works fine ,thank you for your complete explanation

Comment: do you know how can I select changed element?! here inputs in new form? @Satpal

Comment: @Ali, I didn't get your question?

Answer (score 2):

When `<input type="checkbox" name="set_address" checked>` is replaced, you lose the event handling functions that were attached to it.

Instead, delegate your event handler:

```
$('form').on('change', 'input[name="set_address"]', function () {
    $('input[name="university"]').prop('disabled',false);
    $('input[name="school"]').prop('disabled',false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use delegate

```
$(document.body).on("change",'input[name="set_address"]', function () {
```